# Need to enable my AMD Radeon GPU to be detected by tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I have been training my T5 transformer models on Google Colab where I had access to a cloud GPU.

Now, I am trying to copy all my code to PyCharm IDE (therefore, will need to access my own GPU)

However, I am facing the following errors:

```
2022-02-02 17:46:14.210695: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found

2022-02-02 17:46:14.210880: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

After looking online, I have seen that AMD Radeon GPU does not support CUDA but OpenCL.

1. I have followed this link https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-SDK to install OpenCL, vcpkg dependencies etc
2. I installed CMake to build and install SDK with samples which is on the bottom of the link's page above (not sure if I need it) but I am facing errors too.
3. if I run `print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))`

   then I am getting => `Num GPUs Available:  0`

Not sure if that means that my first GPU (0) is available as if I go to my Task Manager I can see:

**GPU 0: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620**

**GPU 1: AMD RADEON(TM) 530**

***Note:***
If I had NVIDIA GPU, then it would be too easy to solve the problem as there are many guides online but not in my case

Comment: Tensorflow does not detect any GPU in your system. Instead of compiling, I would use the AMD Tensorflow docker image.